# what is に's function in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> こうした近代における新しい民族併合の過程は、他の民族に対する強制や差別など、古代から民族の形成を通じて共感を形作ってきた単一民族としてのアイデンティティに、多くの問題を引き起こした。

I am trying to contract this sentence

> この過程はアイデンティティに、多くの問題を引き起こした

but I still can't figure out に's role in this sentence,anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The に particle here marks or indicates what kind of / examples of "many problems that have occurred" (多くの問題を引き起こした) when it comes to "new ethnic group merge processes in the present day" (こうした近代における新しい民族併合の過程)

Everything preceding the に up to the は are the problems the writer is talking about:

1. Things such as coercion and discrimination in regards to other ethnic groups (他の民族に対する強制や差別など)
2. Identity in terms of race homogeny when it comes to understanding ethnic group formation since ancient times and empathy that has formed (古代から民族の形成を通じて共感を形作ってきた単一民族としてのアイデンティティ)

When I read your condensed version, I see the に filling the same role more or less. It marks "identity" as the thing / area where "many problems that have occurred" are in regards to "this process". Overall, I read it as:

> This process has had many problems that have occurred with identity

Also, the comma / spacing (、) that comes after the に is just to make it easier to read / for the benefit of the reader